Integrate function that approaches infinity at $x=1$
$$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{\ln ^2(x)} \, dx$$
This integral doesn't seem to have a solution with elementary functions, but is it possible for me to express it in terms of $\operatorname {Li}$ or other functions?

Why do you think the function going to infinity at $x=1$ is a problem? The function $\frac{1}{x-1}$ goes to infinity at $x=1$ but has the antiderivative $\log(|x-1|)$ for all $x\ne 1$.

@jjagmath for $\frac{1}{x-1}$, it has both $-\infty$ and $\infty$, which makes them cancel out

No, the infinites does not "cancel out". The function $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ goes to $+\infty$ from both sides and has the antiderivative $\frac{1}{1-x}$ for all $x\ne 1$.

for integration like $\frac{1}{x}$, the result is actually $\ln{x} + C_1$ and $\ln{x} + C_2$

Still don't see any problem with your function going to infinity at $x=1$.

my fault, it's probably my misunderstanding of integration, but still, how can i integrate this

I doubt this integral can be written in terms of elementary functions or even using the usual special functions.
